# Data is displayed only after resfresh the page

Tags: angular

Could someone help me understand asynchronicity in Angular? I'm using the rest api and my data only displays when the page is refreshed. I don't know how to make using the api display the data immediately. Another issue is also that many times I 'shoot' for api. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I tried something like this:

service:

```
getData(data: any): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post(this.myUrl, data)
}
```

ts:

```
item: [];

ngOnInit() {
this.getMethod();
this.querySubscription = this.apollo
      .watchQuery<any>({
        query: GET_POSTS,
      })
      .valueChanges.subscribe(({ data }) => {
        this.myData$ = data.items.myData;
        this.getMethod();
      });
  }
}

getMethod() {
const data: // some data
this.myService.getData(data).subscribe((res) => {
this.item = res;
}
}

itemMethod(title: string) {
// some code
}
```

in html I pass the itemMethod.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myList">
<h1>{{itemMethod(item.title)}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you can use the `async` pipe to handle asynchronous data in templates.

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe):

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
> latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async
> pipe marks the component to be checked for changes.

Your service:

```
getData(): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>('https://api.example.com/data');
}
```

Your component:

```
data$: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.data$ = this.dataService.getData();
}
```

Your template:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of data$ | async">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```